# Reading books and checking websites has/have helped them

Tags: grammar

Which is more correct to say?

*Reading books and checking websites **has** helped them.*

*Reading books and checking websites **have** helped them.*

Comment: Both are acceptable, check with the topic of "notional agreement" or "synesis". If you see both activities as one undertaking, then there's no reason you can't use "has" instead of "have". The boring example I keep bringing up is "The band are/is playing". Also, there are many questions on this site about this topic.

Comment: Also how related the subjects are can matter, see this example: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pain+and+suffering+is%2Cpain+and+suffering+are&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpain%20and%20suffering%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpain%20and%20suffering%20are%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I can only make *have* work if you treat *reading* and *checking* as adjectives.  I.e., there are math books, writing books and reading books  and there are websites that test things (testing websites) and websites that check things (checking websites).  Both reading books and checking websites have helped them.  But I'm sure that's not the intended meaning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Agreement With Compound Subjects Joined by And](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117346/agreement-with-compound-subjects-joined-by-and)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Singular vs. Plural with Multiple Gerunds as Subject (IE: \[Gerund\] and \[Gerund\] are/is \[something\].)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116240/singular-vs-plural-with-multiple-gerunds-as-subject-ie-gerund-and-gerund)

Answer (score -1):

Think of ‘reading books and checking websites’ as being ‘an activity’. A completed ‘activity’.

‘Something you did’, which collectively is ‘activity’. This makes it, in English ‘one thing’ (implied).

So we would use ‘has’, which refers to the singular. ‘Have’, in my view, is absolutely not correct in this sentence and sounds very weird to my (English!) ears - iffff... those sentences are complete.

Howeverrr...

...If you continued on with the second sentence - for example:

‘Reading books and checking websites have helped them to gain a further understanding of the Italian Renaissance’

Then in that case, we do need to say ‘have’. Because now, what is implied is ‘the activities’. Multiple and discrete ‘activities’. Which then takes the plural.

Whyyyy?

- Single things (even when ‘implied’) take the singular ‘has’

‘This completed activity or group of activities’ (perceived as one thing - ‘this activity’ - singular) has helped them

- Multiple things (even when implied) take the plural ‘have’

‘These two activities’ (perceived as multiple things) have helped them

In a nutshell: use ‘has’ when you want to refer to the individual activities that took place. Use ‘have’ when you want to refer to ‘the activity’ (or ‘effort) that ‘went on’.

Comment: It's what I always do, and you explain synesis well (it's been done here before), but there are those who stick to 'grammatical form' agreement. 'England has scored.' No grammar czar has appeared to say whether one approach or the other must be ditched.

Answer (score -3):

The second is correct in this instance. Because there are two subjects joined by *and*, the subject is plural and requires a plural verb. Gregg's Reference Manual (11th ed.) paragraph 1002a explains this as follows:

> If the subject consists of two or more words that are connected by *and* or by *both ... and*, the subject is plural and requires a plural verb.

Comment: In that case, would the phrase "Reading the book and checking this website has helped them." be correct?

Comment: I think it should be **have** in that instance as well, but I'm having a hard time finding a specific supporting source. An easier way to get around has vs. have might be to change the sentence to get rid of the ambiguous _checking_; in most cases, _reading_ could apply both to books and websites. Therefore, "Reading the book and this website has helped them..." would work because the subject is the singular _Reading_. (Using this logic, the original question asked would be "Reading books and websites has helped them...".)

Comment: */??Fish and chips are what we had for tea.