# Verb agreement with two gerunds as subject

Tags: verbs, gerunds, subjects, agreement

I would like to know which of the following sentences is correct:

*Translating and adapting texts for different audiences **composes** the key of this theory*

*Translating and adapting texts for different audiences **compose** the key of this theory*

The word "texts" is related to both subjects, hence the doubt. Lastly, is the use of **for** in "for different audiences" correct as well?

Comment: Sorry, those are indeed gerunds, though they've been reduced by Conjunction Reduction. The constituent _Translating ... audiences_ is a noun phrase, and the subject of _composes_, which is third person singular because all noun phrases that are clauses are third person singular by default. Therefore _composes_ takes the _-s_ suffix. Oh, and _for_ is fine for the intended audiences

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Singular vs. Plural with Multiple Gerunds as Subject (IE: \[Gerund\] and \[Gerund\] are/is \[something\].)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116240/singular-vs-plural-with-multiple-gerunds-as-subject-ie-gerund-and-gerund)

Answer (score 3):

> Non-finite clauses take singular agreement, so "composes" is correct. The fact that the subject has a coordination of two VPs makes no difference -- it's a single clause and as such takes a singular verb. Compare, by contrast, "Skating on the lake and swimming in the stream" are my favourite activities, where there is a coordination of two separate clauses, requiring a plural verb
>
> Further, what composes the key of this theory is the combination of the two actions, not each of them individually, so a singular verb is usual. It is not the equivalent to the clausal coordination in, say, "Translating texts for different audiences and adapting suitable texts", where the expected verb would be a plural one.

— [BillJ](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/141248/billj) comments from 2019-04-12.

Comment: I agree. The two ING verbs are coordinated within the verb phrase "translating and adapting texts for different audiences". The fact that they take an object and the possibility of their adverbial modification provide firm evidence of the formal status of "translating and adapting"

Answer (score 1):

If the act of "translating" is part of the act of "adapting", then these two are considered as one action, and therefore, you use "composes".

If "translating" and "adapting" are two separate processes for your intended work, then they should be treated as separate actions, and therefore, the verb "compose" should be used.

--The use of "for" is acceptable in this sentence.

--Consider using "the" before texts, if you have already referred to these "texts" and/or you have defined the types of these texts.